# I want to add images to the links with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, web

When you hover the links (every link has a different image) image must  shown in the div. How can i do it? I have to do it with javascript not css, and i don't wan to use `innerHTML`.

```js
 window.addEventListener("load",function(){
            var backG=document.getElementById("b");
            backG.style.backgroundColor="#eee";       
            var h=document.getElementById("head");
            h.style.textAlign="center";
            h.style.margin="50px";
            var x=document.getElementById("ulist");
            x.style.textAlign="center";
            var lis=x.getElementsByTagName("li");   
            for(var i=0;i<lis.length;i++){
                lis[i].style.display="inline";
            } 
            var links=x.getElementsByTagName("a");
            for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
                links[i].style.textDecoration="none";
                links[i].style.border="1px solid black";
                links[i].style.padding="10px";
                links[i].style.color="blue";              
            }
            var boxDiv=document.getElementById("box");
            boxDiv.style.border="1px solid blue";
            boxDiv.style.width="500px";
            boxDiv.style.height="500px";
            boxDiv.style.margin="50px 525px";
            boxDiv.style.backgroundColor="white";
            });
```

```html
<h1 id="head">Move Your Mouse Over Links For Different Images</h1>
<ul id="ulist">
    <li><a href="#link">image 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#link">image 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#link">image 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#link">image 4</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="box">
</div>
```

Comment: So you add a mouseover event....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working snippet. No jquery, no css, just vanilla js. Please see if it works for you. The box background image is updated according to the `href` attribute from the list item's inner element. Background position, repeat and other attributes can be adjusted as needed.

```js
var boxDiv = document.getElementById("box");
boxDiv.style.border = "1px solid blue";
boxDiv.style.width = "500px";
boxDiv.style.height = "500px";
boxDiv.style.backgroundColor = "white";

var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  list[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
    //console.log(event.target.href);
    href = event.target.href;
    boxDiv.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + href + ')';
  })
}
```

```html
<h1 id="head">Move Your Mouse Over Links For Different Images</h1>
<ul id="ulist">
  <li><a href="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">image 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://via.placeholder.com/200x150">image 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://via.placeholder.com/100x150">image 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://via.placeholder.com/350x450">image 4</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="box">
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! just one more thing, i am new at this topics so... how can i change the background color of the llinks when mouse over the links?

Comment: You are welcome. To change the background just use css `:hover` pseudo-class. For instance: `li:hover {background-color:red}`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a onmouseover event to each link that tied to one function like this.

```
    <ul id="ulist">
    <li><a onmouseover='showImg(this)' href="#link">image 1</a></li>
    <li><a onmouseover='showImg(this)' href="#link">image 2</a></li>
     --> etc... <--
  </ul>

  <script>
  function showImg(obj) {
     var elem = document.createElement("img");
     //create img element

     elem.src = obj.href;
     //set img src from href of link that mouse is hovering over       

     document.getElementById('#imgDiv').appendChild(elem);
     //append img element to div
   }  
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to change background of the div to an image when `mouseover` event occurs on any of the links:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  // your code here
  var boxDiv = document.querySelector("#box");
  boxDiv.style.border="1px solid blue";
  boxDiv.style.width="500px";
  boxDiv.style.height="500px";

  var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
  links.forEach(function (e) {

    e.addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
      var imageUrl = event.target.getAttribute("data");
      boxDiv.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + imageUrl + ")";
    })

  });
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>title</title>
</head>
<body id="b">
<h1 id="head">Move Your Mouse Over Links For Different Images</h1>
<ul id="ulist">
  <li><a href="#link" data="https://images.pexels.com/users/avatars/293608/oleg-magni-245.jpeg">image 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link" data="https://images.pexels.com/users/avatars/224453/bruce-mars-661.jpeg">image 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link" data="https://images.pexels.com/users/avatars/68/tim-savage-370.jpeg">image 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link" data="https://images.pexels.com/users/avatars/91955/rawpixel-com-856.png">image 4</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="box">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I moved the JavaScript code in a separate file just to make things clearer.